# How to escape `$like` wildcard characters `%` and `_` in sequelize?

Tags: javascript, sqlite, sequelize.js

How does one tell sequelize (using sqlite3) to escape wildcard characters (`%`,`_`) in a `$like` clause?

For example, I'd like to generate a query comparable to the one below which finds the literal string `_cool_` in any "things.description" (not just the word "cool" surrounded by any characters):

```javascript
SELECT * FROM things WHERE description LIKE '\_cool\_' ESCAPE '\';
```

I'm guessing it would look something like this but the resulting query is not what I would hope:

```javascript
Thing.findAll({
  where: {
    description: {
      $like: ['?', '_cool_'],
      // ... or ...
      $like: '\\_cool\\_',
      $escape: '\\',
    }
  }
});

// => Executing (default):
// SELECT `id`, `description`
//   FROM `Things` AS `Thing`
//   WHERE `Thing`.`description` LIKE '?','_cool_';
```

Unfortunately I cannot drop into a raw query because the "LIKE" clause will be part of a larger dynamic query.

Any ideas?

Comment: Wouldnt that be `\_cool\_` if you're escaping a singular backslash?

Comment: @Xorifelse in JavaScript the string literal `'\\_'` equals the string `"\_"`.

Comment: Looks like this may just be a current shortcoming in sequelize https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4317

Answer (score 3):

A full solution based on @piotrbienias that takes any user input and properly escapes it -

```
if (typeof query.string !== 'string') {
    throw Error('expecting string')
}
const inputRaw = query.string.replace(/(_|%|\\)/g, '\\$1');
const inputSec = sequelize.escape(`%${inputRaw}%`);
description = {
    $like: sequelize.literal(`${inputSec} ESCAPE '\\'`)
};
```

For the example string `_cool_` this will translate to -

```
LIKE '%\\_cool\\_%' ESCAPE '\\'
```

You can change the logic to add other wildcards depending on your actual use case

if your using mysql and not sqlite the default escape is anyway `\` so the ESCAPE declaration can be removed

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that comes to my mind is something like

```
description: {
    $like: sequelize.literal(`'\\_cool\\_' ESCAPE '\\'`)
}
```

That generates SQL like

```
LIKE '\_cool\_' ESCAPE '\'
```

Comment: Good idea, just need to be careful to escape the target value itself to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: Sequelize offers [`escape`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/sequelize/#escapevalue-string) method that can be used to escape value to avoid injection